# Can Wall of Stone be used to make an enclosed structure?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell requires "must be contiguous with at least one other panel" and that you can "crudely shape the wall to create crenellations, battlements, and so on."

Adding a roof to make an enclosed space seems to be 'permissible' within the limitations, but is it allowed since that's not really a wall?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In short: **YES**

> The   wall    can have    any shape   you desire, though  it  can’t   occupy  the same    space   as  a   creature    or  object. The wall    doesn’t need    to  be  vertical    or  rest    on  any firm    foundation. It  must,   however,    merge   with    and be  solidly supported   by  existing    stone.  Thus,   you can use this    spell   to  bridge  a   chasm   or  create  a   ramp.

This is a spell that is often overlooked as one of the most utilitarian there is. As long as the creation is simple (as in not elaborate), then yes. I have always thought of using that spell as something to do with Graham Crackers: box-shape and simple.

Comment: I understand that it's part of the "WALL" family, but this behaves so differently it seems like they should have called it something else.